# Push notification does not send from console using Azure

Tags: c#, azure, azure-notificationhub

I have created a Notification Hub using [this guide](https://azure.microsoft.com/da-dk/documentation/articles/xamarin-notification-hubs-push-notifications-android-gcm/) and [these instructions](https://github.com/Azure/azure-content/blob/master/includes/notification-hubs-enable-firebase-cloud-messaging.md) (for how to add Firebase to Azure).

When I send using Test Send on Azure, the push notification is send successfully. But when I send it using their Console Example in the previous mentioned guide, it simply crashes when using `SendGcmNativeNotificationAsync`-method. 
What can be wrong?

My namespace contains letters and a `-`, but my name for the hub contains `_` too. Can that be the problem (and if it is, why did they not tell me during creation)?

***EDIT***: Modified code

```
var connectionStr = ServiceBusConnectionStringBuilder.CreateUsingSharedAccessKey(new Uri({uri}), "DefaultSendSharedAccessSignature", "Ln4em6ZqeukRS3y1Hgq/3m5V2S51IBIkG7tk+MAfO/Y=");

var hub = NotificationHubClient.CreateClientFromConnectionString(connectionStr, {hub-name});

await hub.SendGcmNativeNotificationAsync("{ \"data\" : {\"message\":\"Hello from Azure!\"}}");

Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: I don't think your namespace or hub name having those symbols has something to do with the crash. (If it had, the test send most likely wouldn't have worked either.) When `SendGcmNativeNotificationAsync`crashes, do you have any error message or stack trace? Could you update the question with the code snippet of how you call the method?

Comment: I don't have any error messages or stack traces, as I exit with code 0. I am going to update the answer now.

Comment: How are you identifying who the push should be sent to? Are you expecting this to go to every register device?

Comment: Yes, I am expecting it to go to all Android devices

Comment: Could you update the question with the payload that you're submitting to the test send? And are you sure you have your GCM key configured and that you do have Android registrations?

Comment: Do you mean connection string and hub name or? Yes, I am cause when I send with Test Send on Azure's portal, it works

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
private static async void SendNotificationAsync()  
{  
    NotificationHubClient hub = NotificationHubClient  
        .CreateClientFromConnectionString("<connection string with full access>", "<hub name>");  
    var notif = "{ \"data\" : {\"message\":\"" + "Hola" + "\"}}";  
    await hub.SendGcmNativeNotificationAsync(notif);  
}
```

Obtained from: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/sending-notification-from-a-console-application-using-notification-hubs

The connection string can be found in your Notification Hub (Access Policies):
[image]

It worked for me for a simple console App Test.

Comment: Sorry, couldn't notice the difference between your code suggestion and the code provided in the question. can you pinpoint it for us?

Comment: @AmjadHusseini you're right; it simply worked for me at first try